# Append numbers to the lists based on the number of divs

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a class="pagination".  Inside are lists.  Using my code, how can I append the numbers to the lists based on the number of divs that are already displayed? Please see below.

```
<div>
    <div class="divs"></div>
    <div class="divs"></div>
    <div class="divs"></div>
</div>

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Using the script:

```
$(function()
    {
        $('#list .list-container.active').each(function()
        {
            var pgeCnt = $(this);
            var pgeCount = 0;
            pgeCnt.find('.list-barrel').each(function()
            {
                pgeCount++;
                var pageContent = '<li>' + pgeCount + '</li>';
                console.log(pgeCount);
                $('.pagination').append(new Array(pgeCount).join(pageContent))
            });
        });
    });
```

I tried to manipulate my script but somehow all I'm getting is "2 3 3", instead of "1 2 3".  (That is a pagination list by the way).

Answer (score 0):

pgeCount++;

Get this line at the end of the foreach instead of the beginning of it like:

```
pgeCnt.find('.list-barrel').each(function()
            {
                var pageContent = '<li>' + pgeCount + '</li>';
                console.log(pgeCount);
                $('.pagination').append(new Array(pgeCount).join(pageContent))
                pgeCount++;
            });
```

Comment: Not quite it. It's producing only this:  <li>2</li>. What I need is `<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>`